# MYSQL select the date from one table that not exist in the second table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

i have 2 tables

```
presence table:

matricule  date_effet
248        2017-01-30
248        2017-01-31
248        2017-02-01
248        2017-02-02
```

Activities table :

```
Matricule    date
248        2017-01-31
248        2017-02-01
248        2017-02-02
```

what i want is to extract the dates that exist on the first one and don't exist in the second one in this case 2017-01-30 knowing that the user will select a range date for exemple in this case maybe date between 2017-01-28 and 2017-02-02

Comment: There are many ways to to it, left join using null check (negative outer join), using `not exists`. Please try something and let us know if you get stuck. You can see how the above mentioned approach works by googling.

Comment: thnks for the help i'm still trying my best lol and i will let u know, i did triyed not exists but didn't work

Comment: Here are 2 queries to do the job `select p.date_effet from presence p
where not exists (
  select 1 from activities a
  where a.date = p.date_effet
)` 

And other way is `select p.date_effet from presence p left join activities a on a.date = p.date_effet where a.date is null;`

Comment: sorry but i tried the 2 of them and it didn't work

Comment: Not sure what you are trying and how here is a working example http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d670c/2

Comment: SELECT p.date_effet FROM presence p 
LEFT JOIN activities a ON p.matricule=a.matricule AND p.date_effet=a.date WHERE a.matricule is null;

Comment: thanks  bro i really apreciate ur  help  this query  above worked for  me

Answer (score 0):

try with

```
SELECT * FROM presence
MINUS 
SELECT * FROM Activities
```

from [SQL EXCEPT / MINUS](https://sql.sh/cours/except)

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* and *why* this solves the problem. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT date_effet FROM presence WHERE date_effet NOT IN(SELECT date FROM activities)
```

The inner SELECT statement will select all the dates from second table, and then the first select will select all the dates from first table which do not exist in the second table.

Hope it helps!

Comment: thnks for the quick responce but mysql return nothing even i habe a lot of data on my database that should be returned